# Data remain on hard disk after dd command

Tags: system-installation, dd, ubuntu-minimal

After several experiments with Ubuntu mini, I have discovered something strange.

When I want to start a new installation, I boot the system to the Ubuntu mini image, I let it continue to the language selection menu and then I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and start a terminal session using the corresponding option in the menu that appears. In that session, I issue `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=4M count=1` to erase the first 4 MB of the hard disk. Then I reboot the system and start the installation the normal way on a completely wiped disk, or so I thought...

As the installation continues, when it reaches the point where it asks for a host name, it always displays the computer name the previous installation use to use, before I issued the `dd` command.

Secondly, in all the cases I had used the internal hard disk on a software RAID configuration before erasing it, using `dd`, the new installation would always find thet there **still is** an active RAID array on the disk after  it had been erased by `dd`. In order to delete that array I have to use the corresponding option in the *Configure software array* menu.

The strange thing is that everything else, like previous partitions and the previous partition table itself, have been erased completely. How come the information I mentioned above is still maintained after `dd` was used? Why aren't they deleted too?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't even think it will reuse the hostname from a previous install that *hasn't* been deleted.  It is generated based on your name and the bios model.  Raid signatures are stored at the end of the disk or partition these days, so if you used a whole disk raid array ( instead of partitioning the disk first, then creating a raid array out of a partition ), then it isn't going to be wiped by that command.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that detail about where the raid signatures are stored. That explains things of course. As for the hostname, let me give you an example. I had installed android-x86 before I erased the disk using `dd`. I used `dd` as described and when the ubuntu mini installation asked for the new hostname, it automatically displayed **android x86-some_release_number**. This means that it had been saved somewhere and the installer found it and displayed it.